# Visual studio code integrated terminal unresponsive

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed vscode on my ubuntu machine.
Opening it up and choosing Terminal -> New terminal opens up an integrated terminal. However, there is just a white marker where the working directory should be, and it is completely unresponsive. I have read the vscode troubleshooting and search here, but can find anything about it. What is wrong? See image of unresponsive terminal below.

[image]

Comment: Can you use the drop down menu (select) at the top right of the terminal or it does not respond either? Looks like VSCode doesn't recognize the default shell ... There should be the name next to the "1". Did you try to set the default shell in `settings.json`? (e.g. :   `"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"`)